# Getting 400 Bad Request when deploying to Maven Central with gpg:sign-and-deploy-file

Tags: java, maven, sonatype, maven-central

I have a .jar file that I want to upload to Maven Central using Travis. The Jira ticket to create an account was sent to Sonatype by my company, and the account has been created.

The command I have put in the Travis script to upload the artifact is the following:

```
mvn gpg:sign-and-deploy-file \
  -DpomFile=stuff/pom.xml \
  -Dfile=_build/java/Packager.jar \
  -Durl=https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/ \
  -DrepositoryId=maven-central \
  -Dgpg.passphrase=${mvn_passphrase}
```

The output of the command ends with the following error:

```
Uploading to maven-central: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect-sdk/18.0/connect-sdk-18.0.jar
Uploading to maven-central: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect-sdk/18.0/connect-sdk-18.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.115 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-15T16:48:51Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign-and-deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.cloudblue:connect-sdk:jar:18.0 from/to maven-central (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Transfer failed for https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect-sdk/18.0/connect-sdk-18.0.jar 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
```

These are the contents of the ~ /.m2/settings.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>maven-central</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <!-- These will be replaced by the proper env vars by the Travis script -->
            <username>__USER__</username>
            <password>__PASSWORD__</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cloudblue</groupId>
    <artifactId>connect-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Connect Java SDK autogenerated from Haxe sources.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/cloudblue/connect-java-sdk</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>CloudBlue</name>
            <email>connect-service-account@ingrammicro.com</email>
            <organization>CloudBlue</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://www.cloudblue.com/</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/cloudblue/connect-java-sdk.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com:cloudblue/connect-java-sdk.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/cloudblue/connect-java-sdk</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-deploy-plugin.version>3.0.0-M1</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <repositoryId>maven-central</repositoryId>
                            <file>connect.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-gpg-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.8</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>maven-central</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Snapshot</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Release</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Could someone provide guidance on what could be the cause of the 400 error?

**EDIT:** I found out the cause of one of the problems. The groupId was not set to the proper value when creating the Sonatype account. It has been fixed. Now, using the `deploy:deploy-file` goal uploads the packages correctly, but using the `gpg:sign-and-deploy-file` one to sign and upload the files raises the following error:

```
Uploading to connect: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar
Uploaded to connect: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar (374 kB at 19 kB/s)
Uploading to connect: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.pom
Uploaded to connect: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.pom (3.7 kB at 6.2 kB/s)
Downloading from connect: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from connect: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar.asc
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.cloudblue:connect.sdk:18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar.asc from/to connect (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2): Transfer failed for https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar.asc 400 Bad Request
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  27.511 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-17T08:00:16Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign-and-deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.cloudblue:connect.sdk:18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar.asc: Could not transfer metadata com.cloudblue:connect.sdk:18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar.asc from/to connect (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2): Transfer failed for https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/cloudblue/connect.sdk/18.0/connect.sdk-18.0.jar.asc 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, have you verified that `_build/java/Packager.jar` exists?

Comment: Yes, and it is being correctly signed, as _build/java/Packager.jar.asc file also exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same question, we did the following:

- Sign and Deploy to a local directory:
  e.g. `mvn gpg:sign-and-deploy-file -e -X -Durl="file:///tmp"`
- Upload to maven with curl: see: 
  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465868-Uploading-to-a-Staging-Repository-via-REST-API

Comment: Could you share the curl command you used to upload the files? I'm getting 400 with "Missing request entity".

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the REST API to upload all the artifacts and it worked wonderfully. Maven seemed to be working randomly. Sometimes it was uploading the signature files, most times it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

I was silly enough to include the path to my project pom.xml instead of the jar pom in the pomFile param, which also caused this error.
Hope to help some of my peers out with this.